# How can i start itertools combinations from specific letter/digit?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a code like this:

```
start = 1
end = 2
for length in range(start, end+1):
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
```

this will print every uppercase/lowercase letter from A to Z and after all letters are finished, It will start printing all digits from 0 to 9. so it looks like this: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`

After first cycle is done, it goes on second one and does the same thing.
like this:

First cycle starting: a

Second cycle starting: aa

and etc.

## what i want it to do:

I want to start combinations from specific letter or digit.

Like this:

**Combination 1:**

First cycle starting: b

Second cycle starting: ba

*If it is not possible, then like this:*

**Combination 2:**

First cycle starting: b

Second cycle starting: bb

Comment: You could use `product` with two different lists instead, but this will produce more elements than combinations, or just trim the first element of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for all possible permuations after a certain index in which case you can do:

```
import string
import itertools

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def alpha_perms(index):

    return list(itertools.permutations(chars[index:]))

print(alpha_perms(0)) #0th index to go along with the below statement
```

Although... this will most likely (absolutely) freeze your machine. There are 62 characters in `chars` thats `62!` (62 factorial) which is approximately equal to ***3.1469973e+85*** or **~π*10^85th** power possible combinations assuming you passed in the 0th index. Even a reasonable index is going to take a long time.

Alternatively, since using `return list(...)` will cause problems for high combination possibilities. You could `yield` the value

```
import string
import itertools

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def alpha_perms(index):

    for perm in itertools.permutations(chars[index:]):
         yield perm
```

Comment: so for example, if i add:  `print(alpha_perms(52))` will it start from letter Z?

Comment: Also this may be better suited to be turned into a generator and instead `yield` the value so he doesn't have crashing of his computer unless he decides to iterate over the entire generator.

Comment: Should full code look like this?: `import string
import itertools

def loop(index):
start = 1
end = 2
for length in range (start, end+1)
    for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
        chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        return list(itertools.permutations(chars[index:]))
        print(alpha_perms(0))`

Comment: I'd suggest `for perm in itertools.permutations(chars[index:]):
        yield perm`

Comment: And then so he only iterates over part of it something like this. `for i, x in enumerate(alpha_perms(51)):
    if i >= 5:
        break
    else:
        print(x)`

Comment: should i start loop with that? @Signal

Comment: Yes to loop through the generator object.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to print it on screen though, i want it to fill HTML form with mechanize, since i'm new to itertools, can i ask how is it possible?

Comment: @ShellRox *why* do you want to do this? :)

Comment: @Slayer I recommend [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)

Comment: @Signal i'm not doing this to damage anything or anybody else, im just trying to make it for educational purposes.

Comment: @ShellRox If your pentesting *and don't have a supercomputer* I really recommend using a dictionary(You will **never** get through all pi^85 attempts....) . Also if your brute-forcing why this pattern? (assuming this is on a site you have permission to do this on)

Comment: @Signal I am testing multi processing method, So it can be like this: From A to Z, From B to Z, From C to Z, From D to Z and etc.

Comment: Again still don't see this being feasible, but you're better off posting a new question or finding another existing one along the lines of the more general 'How to fill out HTML form via mechanize` and tag it with [python] because as it is this question is getting *very specific*

Comment: I had 1 hour research, but i didn't find anything matching my question, not HTML only, even yielding arguments, Anyways thanks for helping :)

Comment: Note: `3.14e85` is _not_ about `pi^85` (which is merely `1.8e42`) but `pi*10^85`